# how to display data from two or more radio button group

Tags: php

a case like this (this case is about selection of laptop) :
The first form:

```
criteria | select (note : hash mark is checkbox)
price    |    #
brands   |    #
ram      |    #
drive   |    #
```

when i select price and brand then submit, the system will display the form(second form) as below:

**criteria price**

```
sub-criteria  | select (mark o is radio button)
> 7 million   |   O 
5-7 million    |  O 
3-5 million     | O 
1-3 million    |  O
```

**criteria brands**

```
subcriteria  |  select
compaq        |   O
toshiba        |  O
Asus          |  O
samsung        |  O
```

when i select subcriteria price is > 7 million and subcriteria brands are the compaq
the system will display a laptop that has both criteria. just as below(this is third form):

```
name           | brand |       price |          harddrive |        etc
compaq 510    |  compaq |     8 million|      2GB  |            etc
```

I success to display the criteria in the second form. but I have not success to view laptop (on third form) based subcriteria that i choose use radio button on second form.
i use php.

Comment: How are you storing your end results? Database or php array? Can you post your php code that you have tried.

Comment: can you provide us a relevant code? rather than saying # O